# How To Construct A Shellcode From x64 MASM Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm, shellcode

im trying to make a small messagebox shellcode, using masm assembler, im doing so because im not that familiar with other syntaxes, this is the assembly code `main.asm`:

```
EXTRN __imp_ExitProcess:PROC
EXTRN __imp_MessageBoxA:PROC



.code

$HELLO DB 'MessageBox From Asm', 00H
$WORLD DB 'Hello World !', 00H

main PROC
    sub rsp, 40         
    xor ecx, ecx
    lea rdx, OFFSET $WORLD
    lea r8, OFFSET $HELLO
    xor r9d, r9d
    call  QWORD PTR __imp_MessageBoxA
    xor ecx, ecx
    call  QWORD PTR __imp_ExitProcess
    add rsp, 40
    ret 0
main  ENDP

END
```

im keeping everything as default settings, (i mean in the linker options ...)
so far i tried some tools, but none is talking about masm, i found that `.obj` file may be useful, so i tried:

```
dumpbin /disasm main.obj /rawdata:bytes

Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.31.31107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file main.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

$HELLO:
  0000000000000000: 4D
  0000000000000001: 65 73 73           jae         0000000000000077
  0000000000000004: 61
  0000000000000005: 67 65 42 6F        outs        dx,dword ptr gs:[esi]
  0000000000000009: 78 20              js          000000000000002B
  000000000000000B: 46 72 6F           jb          000000000000007D
  000000000000000E: 6D                 ins         dword ptr [rdi],dx
  000000000000000F: 20 41 73           and         byte ptr [rcx+73h],al
  0000000000000012: 6D                 ins         dword ptr [rdi],dx
  0000000000000013: 00 48 65           add         byte ptr [rax+65h],cl
  0000000000000016: 6C                 ins         byte ptr [rdi],dx
  0000000000000017: 6C                 ins         byte ptr [rdi],dx
  0000000000000018: 6F                 outs        dx,dword ptr [rsi]
  0000000000000019: 20 57 6F           and         byte ptr [rdi+6Fh],dl
  000000000000001C: 72 6C              jb          000000000000008A
  000000000000001E: 64 20 21           and         byte ptr fs:[rcx],ah
  0000000000000021: 00 48 83           add         byte ptr [rax-7Dh],cl
  0000000000000024: EC                 in          al,dx
  0000000000000025: 28 33              sub         byte ptr [rbx],dh
  0000000000000027: C9                 leave
  0000000000000028: 48 8D 15 00 00 00  lea         rdx,[$WORLD]
                    00
  000000000000002F: 4C 8D 05 00 00 00  lea         r8,[$HELLO]
                    00
  0000000000000036: 45 33 C9           xor         r9d,r9d
  0000000000000039: FF 15 00 00 00 00  call        qword ptr [__imp_MessageBoxA]
  000000000000003F: 33 C9              xor         ecx,ecx
  0000000000000041: FF 15 00 00 00 00  call        qword ptr [__imp_ExitProcess]
  0000000000000047: 48 83 C4 28        add         rsp,28h
  000000000000004B: C3                 ret

RAW DATA #1
  00000000: 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 42 6F 78 20 46 72 6F 6D 20  MessageBox From
  00000010: 41 73 6D 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 20  Asm.Hello World
  00000020: 21 00 48 83 EC 28 33 C9 48 8D 15 00 00 00 00 4C  !.H.ì(3ÉH......L
  00000030: 8D 05 00 00 00 00 45 33 C9 FF 15 00 00 00 00 33  ......E3Éÿ.....3
  00000040: C9 FF 15 00 00 00 00 48 83 C4 28 C3              Éÿ.....H.Ä(Ã
```

so i thought, maybe this is the shellcode:

```
0x4D, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0x61, 0x67, 0x65, 0x42, 0x6F, 0x78, 0x20, 0x46,
0x72, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x41, 0x73, 0x6D, 0x00, 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C,
0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64, 0x20, 0x21, 0x00, 0x48, 0x83,
0xEC, 0x28, 0x33, 0xC9, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4C,
0x8D, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45, 0x33, 0xC9, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0xC9, 0xFF, 0x15, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48,
0x83, 0xC4, 0x28, 0xC3
```

but it crashed when testing, any help on the topic would be appreciated, thanks for your time :) .

Comment: im using visual studio 2022 to assemble, idk if thats wrong, this is the linker full command line:

Comment: /OUT:"...ASM.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"...ASM.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /ENTRY:"main" /OPT:REF /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"ASM.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\ASM.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Release\ASM.iobj" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Release\ASM.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

Comment: `call  QWORD PTR __imp_MessageBoxA` isn't going to work when injected anywhere; that's a memory-indirect call using a RIP-relative addressing mode to load a function pointer, as you can see in your disassembly.  You either need to know an absolute address for it (and use that in your machine code), or you'd need to bypass the DLLs and use `syscall` directly. (https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/)  That's non-portable, so you'd need to know the Windows kernel version for the system you're "attacking", and what MessageBoxA does internally.  IDK which is easier.